# Weka plugin to Fiji can it be used in python?

Tags: python, weka

I have used the Weka plugin in Fiji to create a classifier and it gives back an arff file and a .model file (this is the classifier). Do you know if I can implement this into python for use in SVM somehow? This is how I am using Weka in the image. 
[image: weka]

Answer (score 0):

You would probably need to use the weka python library (if it exists) to use the model.